# Pronoun question

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I have a pronoun question, though I am not sure what exact category this question falls into. I'm wondering about what is the best pronoun to use in the following situation:

If the "me" in question is a female first-person narrator, is it best to write:

Unlike me, who always swore *I’d* never get married before the age of thirty,...

or:

Unlike me, who always swore *she'd* never get married until the age of thirty,...

The second sounds better to me for some reason.
Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2):

The second one is the right one from my opinion, since using `who` will refer to yourself as third person

Answer (score 0):

Seems best to avoid the question altogether by writing "Unlike me, who swore never to marry before the age of thirty."  It's hard to imaghine this as an opening sentence due to the "Unlike me" at the beginning, and the narrator may have already revealed herself to be female.